# Как в F# узнать количество знаков после запятой в float?

Tags: .net, f#

Мне нужно превратить float в дробь, например 3.24 в 324 / 100. Для этого мне нужно узнать сколько знаков после запятой в числе, чтобы потом умножить на числитель и знаменатель и получить дробь из целых чисел.

Comment: Бессмысленно узнавать, сколько знаков "после запятой" у float. 3.24 на самом деле может храниться как 3.2399999987 или 3.24000000014

Comment: Я бы уочнил @MBo, тем что у чисел в IEEE 754 в принципе нет ничего похожего на дробную часть.

Answer (score 1):

Я решил свою проблему. Нашёл код в интернете и немного отредактировал. Функция принимает float и возвращает числитель и знаменатель:

```
let toMixedNumber(x : float) =
    let wholePart = float (int x)
    let decimalPt = x % 1.0
    let rec cF(Z : float, i : int, Dm : float, Do : float) =
        match Z % 1.0 > 1e-6, i < 1 with
        | _    , true  -> int ((System.Math.Round(decimalPt * Do)) + (wholePart * Do)), int Do
        | true , false -> cF(1.0/(Z % 1.0), i - 1 , Do, Do * System.Math.Round(1.0/(Z % 1.0)-0.5) + Dm )
        | false, _  -> int ((System.Math.Round(decimalPt * Do)) + (wholePart * Do)), int Do
    decimalPt
    |> fun x -> cF(x, 14, 0.0, 1.0)
```